# Upload Image/File with Jquery ajax in Laravel 5.* error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

This problem confused me. Why my code cannot run on the server (in local runs well). What is wrong with the uploaded code?

I did the first ajax setup for all ( my script )

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {  'X-CSRF-Token' : tokenCsrf,
            // 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
            var message = '';
            if(response.body){
                message = (response.body.msg ? response.body.msg : response.body);
            }else{
                $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                    message += value[0] + '<br/>';
                });
            }
            // scripts
        },
        beforeSend:function(){
            // scripts
        },
        complete:function(){
            // scripts
        },
        done:function(){
            // scripts
        }
    });
```

and script ajax for uploading (cut)

```
var fd = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            // scripts
        }
    });
```

so why in my bankend i use

```
dd($request->all()) // emtpy
```

if in my local work perfectly

UPDATE:

in my backend

```
public function myController(Request $request){
      dd($request->all()); // <<--- empty ( nothing parameter from front)
}
```

in my case, why when submit form empty parameter, If in server, but work in local.

---

#### Solved

I got wrong config in PHP.ini

Comment: what's the error message !

Comment: show your function in the controller and the error as well.

Comment: thank @Amani for edited,

Ok, the error message nothing, I use Illuminate\Http\Request;
and than i use dd($request->all()), 

note : variable $request initial from function maybe like that

public function myController(Request $request){
      dd($request->all()); // <<--- empty ( nothing parameter from front )
}

Comment: `var fd = new FormData($(this)[0]);`  this refer to what? is the ajax call inside a submit event?

Comment: yes @amani this inside submit event.

Comment: do you have `preventDefault` function inside the submit --> `$("#your_form").submit(function(e) {  e.preventDefault(); /*ajax call*/ });`

Comment: Yes, I put preventDefault inside submit event. in my case, why when submit form empty parameter, If in server, but work in local.